# Closure not formed for inner function

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

Here's a simple function with a local function:

```
def raise_to(exp):
    def raise_to_exp(x, exp):
        return pow(x, exp)
    return raise_to_exp
```

Now I expect the local function to close over `exp`, but somehow it doesn't. When I run this:

```
square = raise_to(2)
print(square.__closure__)
```

I get `None`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no closure, no, because the inner function has it's own *local* `exp` variable; you gave it a parameter by that name. The parameter masks the name in the outer scope, so no closure is created for it. The function that is returned requires *two* arguments, and the argument to `raise_to()` is simply ignored:

```
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> def raise_to(exp):
...     def raise_to_exp(x, exp):
...         return pow(x, exp)
...     return raise_to_exp
...
>>> signature(raise_to(2))
<Signature (x, exp)>
>>> square = raise_to(2)
>>> square(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: raise_to_exp() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exp'
>>> square(5, 3)
125
>>> raise_to('This is ignored, really')(5, 3)
125
```

Remove the `exp` parameter from the inner function if you wanted that to be taken from the outer function:

```
def raise_to(exp):
    def raise_to_exp(x):
        return pow(x, exp)
    return raise_to_exp
```

Now `exp` is a closure:

```
>>> def raise_to(exp):
...     def raise_to_exp(x):
...         return pow(x, exp)
...     return raise_to_exp
...
>>> raise_to(2).__closure__
(<cell at 0x11041a978: int object at 0x10d908ae0>,)
>>> raise_to.__code__.co_cellvars
('exp',)
```

The `co_cellvars` attribute on a code object gives you the names of any closed-over variable in the outer scope.

The function that is returned takes one argument, and the argument to `raise_to()` is now actually used:

```
>>> raise_to(2)(5)
25
>>> raise_to('Incorrect type for pow()')(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in raise_to_exp
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'str'
```